# redirect the stdout of a child process to the parent process stdin

Tags: c++, windows, child-process

I want to create a Windows console application that will start a child process running the `cmd` command shell with a command line and display the output created by the child process.

The output from the child process is to be read by the parent process so I need to connect the `stdout` of the child process to the `stdin` of the parent process. The parent process will then read from its `stdin` the output from the child process which the child is writing to its `stdout`. The parent process will display the child output to the parent's `stdout`.

The child process will run the Windows `dir` command with the `cmd` command shell.

My current version is not displaying the `dir` command output. The parent process is not displaying any output other than the output from the `system("pause");`.

My main process:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hStdInRead;
    HANDLE hStdInWrite;

    HANDLE hStdOutRead;
    HANDLE hStdOutWrite;
    HANDLE hStdErrWrite;
    if(!CreatePipe(&hStdInRead,&hStdInWrite,NULL,0))
        return 0;
    if(!CreatePipe(&hStdOutRead,&hStdOutWrite,NULL,0))
        return 0;
    if (!DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), hStdOutWrite, GetCurrentProcess(), &hStdErrWrite, 0, TRUE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))  
    {
        return 0;
    }
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW; 
    si.dwFlags =STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW|STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdOutput = hStdOutWrite;
    si.hStdError = hStdErrWrite;
    si.hStdInput = hStdInRead;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&pi,sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    LPSTR cmd = new char[256*sizeof(char)];
    strcpy_s(cmd,256,"C:\\Windows\\cmd.exe /c dir");
    if(CreateProcess(NULL,cmd,NULL,NULL,true,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi))
    {
        std::cout<<"OK"<<std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hStdOutWrite);
        CloseHandle(hStdInRead);
        char ReadBuff[4096];
        DWORD ReadNum ;
        ZeroMemory(&ReadBuff,4096);
        while(ReadFile(hStdOutRead,ReadBuff,4096,&ReadNum,NULL))
        {   
           std::cout<<ReadBuff<<std::endl;
        }
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,INFINITE);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know where the parent process is blocking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code, here's a cleaned up example that works.

Changes made: Consolidated the pipe set into one array and created enums to denote which has what purpose, makes it a lot clearer than calling something "StdOutRead" and "StdOutWrite".

Created a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure to let us set up the pipes for inheritance, and added code to prevent the parent-side halves of the pipes being inherited.

Removed the STARTF_USESTDHANDLES flag from the process.

Specified a directory for the process to perform it's DIR on.

Ensured that we close all the handles we're not using once the process is started in the parent.

Lastly, I made it drain the file of io in chunks and append the null terminator to the end of a successful buffer so that it can output properly.

```
#define WINDOWS_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>

enum { ParentRead, ParentWrite, ChildWrite, ChildRead, NumPipeTypes };

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[])
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = nullptr;

    HANDLE pipes[NumPipeTypes];
    if (!CreatePipe(&pipes[ParentWrite], &pipes[ChildRead], &sa, 0))
        return 0;
    if (!CreatePipe(&pipes[ParentRead], &pipes[ChildWrite], &sa, 0))
        return 0;

    // make sure the handles the parent will use aren't inherited.
    SetHandleInformation(pipes[ParentRead], HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
    SetHandleInformation(pipes[ParentWrite], HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.hStdOutput = pipes[ChildWrite];
    si.hStdError = pipes[ChildWrite];
    si.hStdInput = pipes[ChildRead];
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    TCHAR cmd[] = _T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c dir c:\\");
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
        return 0;

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pipes[ChildRead]);
    CloseHandle(pipes[ChildWrite]);
    CloseHandle(pipes[ParentWrite]);

    char ReadBuff[4096 + 1];
    DWORD ReadNum;
    for (;;) {
        auto success = ReadFile(pipes[ParentRead], ReadBuff, sizeof(ReadBuff) - 1, &ReadNum, NULL);
        if (!success || !ReadNum)
            break;
        ReadBuff[ReadNum] = 0;
        std::cout << ReadBuff;
    }
    //system("pause");  use Ctrl+F5 or Debug >> Start Without debugging instead.
    return 0;
}
```